# Show submartingale property.

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, stopping-times

Let $\tau$ be a stopping time. Let $X_k$ be iid random variables such that $E[X_i] = m < \infty$. Also, $m>0$.Show that $\sum_{k=1}^{\min(\tau,n)} X_k$ is a submartingale.

We need to show that:
$E[\sum_{k=1}^{\min(\tau,n)} X_k | F_{n-1}] \geq \sum_{k=1}^{\min(\tau,n-1)} X_k$

My attempt: We can easily show that the process $(\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a supermartingale. It follows by Doob's optional sampling theorem, that $E[X_{\tau}] \geq E[x_0]$. Now write:
$$E[\sum_{k=1}^{\min(\tau,n)} X_k|F_{n-1}] = E[\mathbb{1}_{\tau<n}\sum_{k=1}^{\tau} X_k+\mathbb{1}_{\tau \geq n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k | F_{n-1}] = E[\mathbb{1}_{\tau<n}(\sum_{k=1}^{\tau-1}  X_k+X_{\tau})+\mathbb{1}_{\tau \geq n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k | F_{n-1}]$$

From here, I think some of the terms are $F_{n-1}$ measurable. But the $\tau<n$ indicator is confusing me because I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: What is the nature of the sequence $X_1,X_2,\ldots$?

Comment: @JohnDawkins They are iid random variables with finite expectation

Comment: Unless $m\ge 0$, it is unlikely that your stopped sum will be a submartingale.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Yes. I fixed the question.

Comment: do you want to prove that it is a martingale or a **sub**martingale? For the latter, you only have to prove "$\geq$" and not "$=$"...

Comment: @saz Yes submartingale should be $\geq$

Comment: Do you know the optional stopping theorem?

Comment: @saz I know the theorem

Comment: I see. Any ideas how to apply it to prove the statement?

Comment: @saz I don't know how to prove the statement. But the theorem asserts that if we have "some, i,e. sub/sup" martingale condition, then we can write something. But here, we wish to prove the submartingale condition. In other words, in order to use the theorem, we need to have the conclusion drawn from the proof of this question.

Comment: @Ryan yeah, but we know that $(\sum_{k=1}^n X_k)_n$ is a submartingale, right? So...

Comment: @saz Ok. I understand. I am trying to use this fact in my proof now. I will update my attempted solution above.

Comment: @saz Does my attempted solution look correct so far? Please see above. Thank you.

Comment: No, it is not correct. First of all, $(\sum_k x_k)$ is not a supermartingale. Moreover, the optional sampling theorem does **not** state that $\mathbb{E}(X_{\tau}) \geq \mathbb{E}(X_0)$ for any stopping time $\tau$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proof based on direct calculations; it does not use the optional stopping theorem.

For brevity of notation set $S_n := \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$. Obviously,

$$\begin{align*} \sum_{k=1}^{\min\{\tau,n\}} X_k = \left( 1_{\{\tau < n\}} + 1_{\{\tau \geq n\}} ´\right) \sum_{k=1}^n X_k = \underbrace{1_{\{\tau < n\}}S_{\tau}}_{=:Y_1} + \underbrace{1_{\{\tau \geq n\}} S_n}_{Y_2}. \end{align*}$$

As $\tau$ is a stopping time, we have $$\{\tau \geq n\} = \{\tau < n\}^c \in \mathcal{F}_{n-1},$$ and therefore, using pull out,

$$\mathbb{E}(Y_2 \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}) = 1_{\{\tau \geq n\}} \mathbb{E}(S_n \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}).$$

Since $(S_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a submartingale (check it!), we get

$$\mathbb{E}(Y_2 \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}) \geq 1_{\{\tau \geq n\}} S_{n-1}.$$

On the other hand,

$$\{\tau<n\} = \bigcup_{j=0}^{n-1} \{\tau=j\} \tag{1}$$

and so

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(Y_1 \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}) &= \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \mathbb{E}(1_{\{\tau=j\}} S_{\tau} \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}) = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \mathbb{E}(1_{\{\tau=j\}} S_j \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}). \end{align*}$$

As $\{\tau=j\} \in \mathcal{F}_j$, we can use the pull out to conclude

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(Y_1 \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}) = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} 1_{\{\tau=j\}} \mathbb{E}(S_j \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1})  &= \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} 1_{\{\tau=j\}} S_j \stackrel{(1)}{=} 1_{\{\tau<n\}} S_{\tau}. \end{align*}$$

Adding all up gives

$$\mathbb{E} \left( \sum_{k=1}^{\min\{\tau,n\}} X_k\mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1} \right) \geq 1_{\{\tau<n\}} S_{\tau} + 1_{\{\tau \geq n\}} S_{n-1} = S_{\min\{\tau \wedge (n-1)\}}.$$

Comment: The penultimate $=$ should be $\ge$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins You are right; thank you.